# Mysql query issue(how to eliminate records having null value for old_device_id column)

Tags: mysql

**I have two tables**

```
device(id, name)
device_map(email, old_device_id)
```

`device_map` is list of `users` and `old devices`. Some users may not have old devices.

`old_device_id` is `unique` and refers to `id` from device table. But it can also be `null`.

Now I want to have select query on table join.

```
select device.email, device.old_device_id, device.name 
from join of device.id and device_map.old_device_id sort by device.name
```

Some rows in `device_map` which has `old_device_id` null are not selected.

```
SELECT dmap.email, dmap.old_device_id, d.name
FROM device_map dmap 
JOIN device d ON d.id = dmap.old_device_id ORDER BY d.name
```

Comment: Could you provide your SQL? Looks like you're not using LEFT JOIN

Comment: Could also provide us some sample result? Like what data you have and what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT dm.email, dm.old_device_id, d.name
FROM device_map dm 
LEFT JOIN device d ON d.id = dm.old_device_id ORDER BY d.name
```

`INNER JOIN` between `device_map` and `device` tables will automatically eliminate records with `null` value for `old_device_id`.

`LEFT JOIN` will include null records as well.

Comment: I have tried the same query. I want to include all null records too.

Comment: @Durgaprasad: I have changed query. If you want to include null records as well then you should use `left join` instead of `inner join`